# How do you run opennlp SentenceDetector and Tokenizer from a shell script?

Tags: shell, opennlp

I am runnning opennlp sentence detection and tokenizer from a shell script but I keep getting errors: Cannot find or load en-sent.bin / or could not find or load main class opennlp.tools.lang.english.SentenceDetector.
Here is my code:

```
OPENNLP_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-opennlp/1.5.3
export OPENNLP_HOME

CLASSPATH=.:\
$OPENNLP_HOME/libexec/lib/opennlp-tools-1.5.3.jar:\
$OPENNLP_HOME/libexec/lib/opennlp-maxent-3.0.3.jar:\
$OPENNLP_HOME/libexec/lib/jwnl-1.3.3.jar
export CLASSPATH

java -cp opennlp.tools.lang.english.SentenceDetector \
$OPENNLP_HOME/models/en-sent.bin
```

ERROR MESSAGE at the command line: Could not find or load main class Cellar....en-sent.bin

1. When I run the command opennlp on the command line, it does not throw any error, so I know opennlp is installed properly.
2. it works fine in eclipse.

Thank you for your help

Comment: add a `cd /path/to/dir/with/opennlp/classes` (or what ever to get the `SentenceDetector` file in the current dir). Hmm, CLASSPATH looks good, but I don't remember if you need to include it in the `java` cmdline.  Good luck.

Comment: @shellter when you say cd to opennlp/classes do you mean the directory where the jar files are?  for example the opennlp-tools-1.5.2.jar? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because en-sent.bin is missing in the folder where you've opened your command prompt.

You should add all the required opennlp models(.bin files) to the folder where you've opened the command prompt or

open a command prompt where all the model files all present which can be done by `shift + Right click` and `open a new command window here`( or you can just cd to wherever your files are there)

hope this helps!

Comment: @omar glad it helped. an upvote would be great! thanks.

Comment: @Alaye Definitely! sorry I am new to SO. I clicked on votes, is that how I upvote?

Comment: oh i get it! it's fine. :)